# VBA Save cell value to new file without formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of data in Excel that needs to be uploaded somewhere where it will be converted into webpages. One of the columns of this table contains HTML code. For each cell in this column, I need to create an html file from the contents of the cell with no additional formatting. I then need to replace the contents of that cell with the new file name.

Currently I have the following:

```
Sub ExportRangetoFile()
'Update 20130913
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveFile As String
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add

For i = 1 To WorkRng.Rows.Count
    WorkRng.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:="A").Copy
    wb.Worksheets(1).Paste
    wb.SaveAs Filename:="E:\Test\" & i, CreateBackup:=False
Next

wb.Close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

however the wb.SaveAs function automatically formats based on either a fed Format parameter, or if there is no parameter it formats as the current version of excel. I want to just output the contents of the cell into a plaintext file with no formatting at all; how can I do this?

Comment: use `CSV` argument in the Format parameter, otherwise [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+write+data+to+text+file&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS821US821&oq=excel+write+data+to+text+file&aqs=chrome.0.0i457j0i22i30l7.5623j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) are bunch of helpful ways to write directly to text files

Answer (score 0):

### Create Text Files From Cell Values

- Before using the code, adjust the two constants.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub exportRangetoFile()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "F:\Test\2020\64976794\"
    Const FileExtension As String = ".txt"
    
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Selection
        
        Dim Data As Variant
        If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            Data = rng.Value
        Else
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
        End If
        
        With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Dim TextFile As Object
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
                Set TextFile = .CreateTextFile(FolderPath & i _
                  & FileExtension, True)
                TextFile.Write Data(i, 1)
                TextFile.Close
            Next i
        End With
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, just found a similar solution but your code looks much cleaner. Do you know how I would solve the issue of having the saved cell surrounded by quotes due to it being of type String?

Comment: In my solution it would be `TextFile.Write "" & Data(i, 1) & ""`, if I understood correctly. If not, do clarify.

Comment: I didn't understand correctly: `TextFile.Write Mid(Data(i, 1), 2, Len(Data(i, 1)) - 2)` or for `CellData`: `Mid(CellData, 2, Len(CellData) - 2)`.

Comment: So actually your initial solution seems to be working perfectly - it looks like .CreateTextFile and .Write handle the data differently to what I did with ```Open FilePath For Output As #500``` and doesn't surround it with quotes by default. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Just found out: in your solution, you can use `Print` instead of `Write` and you won't get the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found a solution to the primary issue I was having by making the following changes.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim FilePath As String
Dim CellData As String

On Error Resume Next

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For i = 1 To WorkRng.Rows.Count

    FilePath = "E:\Test\" & i & ".html"
    Open FilePath For Output As #500
    
    CellData = WorkRng.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:="A")
    Write #500, CellData
    Close #500
    
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Using .SaveAs could not give the desired results so I found how to write to a file directly instead and updated the code accordingly.

The cell contents are being saved to the file, but I'm now having a new issue where the file contents are surrounded by quotes because the cell is of type String when it's saved. So for example cell A1 has contents `<p>Hello<\p>`, that'll be saved to 1.html as `"<p>Hello<\p>"`